# get current running process

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a program that list all the current processes running in listbox in real time using c#. I had a problem inserting it into the mysql database. I retrieve the data from the threaded listbox of process and then save to database. I had the problem when the listbox refreshes it repeats inserting the same data into mysql database.

Can someone help me about this?

This is the sample code

```
foreach (String item in listBox1.Items)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sample";
    MySqlDataReader msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (msdr.Read())
    {
        var items = msdr["log"].ToString();
        if(items != item)
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO sample values('','"+item+"')";
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    msdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: The obvious problem with your program is what happens when you do `if(items != item)` For example if the first row in the database result contains an item that is not the same you will insert a new item into database, but on the second (or third or nth) row of the database recordset there may be an item that is the same. This scenario would thus cause duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

First:  **never** use strings inside `INSERT` statement. **Always** use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Second:  It depends on *where* this code is called. If it's called in *refresh* event, probabbly the right thing to do is to understand if there is something was changed actually, and only on positive result execute SQL query.

Comment: Actually The code is called inside the threaded listbox. so that when the listbox refreshes it automatically inserts on the database. but unfortunately i got the same data repeating as it refreshes. The idea that i have is that to retrieve first all the data from the database and match with the listbox items. but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @user1643284: may be it's better to move the code into some command, like button click ?

Comment: i have the sample code that get's the realtime running application, if the application is running then it gets into the listbox and when it closes it disappears. i got that code here in stack overflow.

Comment: at this point, may be it's better have running processes in some least, on every update *try* check if there is some difference between collection just get and previous one. If yes, run update...

Answer (score 1):

Something like (not tested):

```
foreach (String item in listBox1.Items)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM sample WHERE log = @log";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", item)
    bool found = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0

    if(!found)
    {

       String query = "INSERT INTO sample values('',@log)";
       cmd.CommandText = query;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", item);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }  
}
```

Comment: I got an error in this part bool found = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0

Comment: Yes, I see. What does the description text of the exception say? Without details of the error there is not much I can suggest... I've tested a similar to my database...